# Why do different trig functions sum differently?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Why does the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin (\frac 1 {n^2})$ converge but the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos (\frac 1 {n^2})$ diverge?

Comment: $\sin x$ is small when $x$ is close to $0$, and $\cos x$ is big.

Comment: I feel stupid that it was that simple... Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: No problem! The comment took little time to type. When one is looking at the convergence/divergence of a series, the first question is not "what test shall we use," it is "about how big is the $n$-th term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin t\approx t$ for small values of the argument. In our case, $t=\dfrac1{n^2}$, which approaches $0$ as *n* tends towards infinity. Therefore, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac1{n^2}\approx\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ , which indeed converges, since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^k}$ always converges for $k>1$. See [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29) and the [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) for more details. On the other hand, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\frac1{n^2}=\cos0=1\neq0$, meaning that the necessary condition for convergence is not met, hence the second series diverges.